# PHP Mysql Insert Into not working, no error given no data posted to DB, earlier the same page was working

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, css

I have problem regarding noted above. My code in php is as under:

```
  $con = mysql_connect(xxxx,xxx,xxx) or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db(xxx) or die(mysql_error());
        if (count($_POST) > 0) echo "form submitted";
        if(isset($submit))
        {
        $name = $_POST['std_name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $pass = $_POST['pass'];
        $user_type = "student";
                    if(mysql_query("insert into login (user_id, user_pass, User_type) values ('$email','$pass','$user_type'", $con))
                    {
                        echo "<p class='success_msg'>Congrats! your registration has successfully been done.</p>";
                        echo mysql_error();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo mysql_error();
                    }
```

Earlier this code was working well and the values were being entered into database. but suddenly it is not working and not even giving any error. any help in the regard will be highly appreciated, please.

Comment: Something obviously changed since it "last" worked. Always work with copies of working code, that way you can revert to it. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: also all your columns start with lower case except 'User_type' fix it if this is a typo

Comment: Plus, this `if(isset($submit))` where is that being defined? If it isn't, then you may need to do something like `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`

Comment: You have a spare `"` in your query line (and a SQL injection vulnerability too).

Comment: Actually I have not included the html code here. this is only PHP code. one bracket is miss to paste here. please suggest some remedial solution. I'm in problem earlier this code worked and no changes are made in it. It's not working now

Comment: @MuhammadAwais Please check my answer again.

Answer (score 1):

- $submit is not set in the code sample
- You are missing a closing bracket at the end of your query
- Read about 'SQL injection', your code is vulnerable

Comment: I'll agree on point number 2 (good catch), but it's unclear as to if `$submit` is in OP's code but isn't showing us. That missing bracket should have triggered an error. OP says *"but suddenly it is not working and not even giving any error"*

Comment: Actual code is here the above is missing.

Comment: Actually I have not included the html code here. this is only PHP code. one bracket is miss to paste here. please suggest some remedial solution. I'm in problem earlier this code worked and no changes are made in it. It's not working now

Comment: I have posted an answer that'll help you out, @MuhammadAwais.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what *might* help...
Connect to your MySQL database via PHPMyAdmin or via SSH.

Once connected, type the query manually (so, INSERT INTO login() etc) — if it works, then it's a bug further up your code. If this is the case, you need to show us more.

OK, so I've applied a nice PDO version down below.

```
$host = "localhost";
$port = 3306;
$dbname = "myDatabase";
$user = "myUser";
$pass = "myPass";
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";port=" . $port . ";dbname=" . $dbname, $user, $pass);

echo (count($_POST) > 0) ? echo "form submitted" : "";
if(isset($submit))
{
    $name = $_POST['std_name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $user_type = "student";
    $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO login(`user_id`, `user_pass`, `User_type`) VALUES (:email, :pass, :utype");
    $binds = array(
      ":email" => $email,
      ":pass" => $pass,
      ":utype" => $user_type
    );
    if($query->execute($binds))
    {
      echo "<p class='success_msg'>Congrats! your registration has successfully been done.</p>";
    }else{
      echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
      print_r($db->errorInfo());
    }
}
```

Read the PDO documentation [here](http://php.net/pdo).

Comment: It might be worth outlining what changes you have made. Is it basically the switch to PDO?

Comment: Still the situation is same. it's not working too.

Comment: Still the situation is same. it's not working too.
- @matrixdevuk

Comment: @halfer — Pretty much, and it's now more secure.

Comment: Fair enough @matrix. It's not _quite_ an answer to the question, but the question isn't answerable in its current form, and will probably close anyway. +1 to counteract the rather hasty -1.